# Linux get Min/Max date column

Tags: linux, date, max, min

I have a very big file (7G), from which I want to extract the Min and Max of a specific date column (it's the 4th column in the file).
Currently, I have this snippet but I'm not sure how efficient it is, and the env. Im working on is sensitive to heavy processing, so if anyone can come up with something not performance costy, I'd appreciate it

```
MIN=`date --date="$1" +%s`
MAX=`date --date="$2" +%s`

while true ; do
read LINE
if [ "$LINE" = "" ] ; then break ; fi

L_DATE=`echo $LINE | awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4}'`
L_DATE=`date --date="$L_DATE" +%s`

if (( $MIN > $L_DATE  )) ; then continue ; fi
if (( $L_DATE <= $MAX )) ; then echo $LINE ; fi
if (( $L_DATE >  $MAX )) ; then break ; fi
```

done

Comment: Reading a file wuth shell `read` and processing each line with awk? Isn't there a law against that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that I often use below solution:

```
sed 1d textfile | awk '{ if($4 > MAX) { MAX=$4} if(($4 < MIN) || MIN =="") {MIN = $4}} END{print MIN"|"MAX }' FS=";"
```

sed 1d will remove the header (remove that part if it is not applicable for your situation).
Also change the FS (Field Separator) accordingly.

Comment: It took about 4 minutes on a 8,4 GB file and awk was using about 60% of CPU and sed 30% (monitored with top).
I made a copy of the file and removed the header, so only the awk statement can be used and then it still takes about 4 minutes and awk will take up 60% of CPU again.

Answer (score 0):

You are running new processes (awk, date and bash again) for each line of the file. I think this is very poor about efficiency.

I would suggest to use some more advance programming language for a task like this instead of bash.

Otherwise if you insist using bash, you could try to not use awk and date. What is the format of your lines? I think you could compare the dates without converting them, and you could replace the awk command with some variable manipulation like ${L_DATE//...}

Otherwise you could try to use awk to parse the whole file...

Comment: so string comparison should be ok to compare dates. I think uou don't need to call awk or date.